# Python gives NotImplementedError for posix grp functions on AIX

Tags: python, jython, aix

I found this problem while using python to extract a tar file, using `tarfile.extractall`. The function works on other OS, but on AIX I get an error originating from `getgrnam`.

Here is a very simple test invoking `getgrnam` only:

```
Jython 2.5.2 (Release_2_5_2:7206, Mar 2 2011, 23:12:06)
[IBM J9 VM (IBM Corporation)] on java1.5.0
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> import grp
>>>
>>> file = "test.txt"
>>>
>>> grp.getgrnam(file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/jython.jar/Lib/grp.py", line 67, in getgrnam
NotImplementedError: getgrnam unimplemented
```

Any idea why this is happening and what a solution might be?

Answer (score 0):

AIX does not appear as POSIX to Jython.